# Make Modernizr.load() add scripts to end of page

Tags: javascript, modernizr, yepnope, polyfills

I am using Modernizr to check for features, namely csscolumns, and running `Modernizr.load()` in order to use the [css3-multi-column.js](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/) polyfill if this feature isn't available. This all works pretty fine, apart from the fact that Modernizr/yepnope inserts the script just before the Modernizr script element and also before my stylesheets. Since `css3-multi-column.js` has to be included after all the stylesheets I would prefer if Modernizr added the script to the end of the page. Is that possible?

This is my code:

```
Modernizr.load({
    test: Modernizr.csscolumns,
    nope: 'http://host.org/js/libs/css3-multi-column.js';
});
```

This is what I would like to accomplish with Modernizr, if possible:

```
if (!Modernizr.csscolumns) {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = 'http://host.org/js/libs/css3-multi-column.js';
    $('body').append(script);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumble on the same problem and took a look at the *Modernizr* ([yepnope.js](https://github.com/SlexAxton/yepnope.js/blob/master/yepnope.js)) code and that's definitely not possible to add the script at the page end.

So, unfortunately, your solution is the good one.

Another possible solution is to put *Modernizr* at the bottom of the page (but IE8 will break, see the bottom note [here](http://modernizr.com/docs/#installing))?

Also, in my case, all my stylesheets were before the `css3-multi-column.js` script inserted by *Modernizr* but it was not working either. But using your method fix the problem. With your method it works also when appending to `HEAD`. So the problem is not with the place where the script is inserted but something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I guess I was too lazy to have a look at the yepnope source. From what I remember Modernizr should load before any js or css, which might be why you couldn't get `yepnope.js` + `css3-multi-coluns.js` working even when loading the it after the stylesheets. Anyway, since posting my question I just accepted the fact that yepnope didn't support appending scripts to the end of the page. And while my alternative code does work fine, I just thought using yepnope would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: Today I tried to load the CSS with *Modernizr* in a way that I was sure it was loaded before `css3-multi-coluns.js` and that didn't work. I also added `script.type="text/javascript"` to the *Modernizr* code without much success. I don't see the difference between the method used in *Modernizr* and your code?

Comment: I agree, as far as I can tell, essentially what Modernizr does is setting the src/href and other attributes and appends script and link elements to the document, i.e. pretty much the same thing as my workaround.